# how to update the quantity if product exists in the cart redcuer react

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with my logic in reducer from add to cart case, if product exist in the cart the quantity its increment 2 amounts per click when the increment should 1 amount per click.

```
export const initialState = {
  basket: [],
};
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'ADD_TO_CART':
        let newCart = [...state.basket]
        let itemInCart = newCart.find((item) => item.id === action.item.id);

        if (itemInCart) {
          itemInCart.quantity++
        } else {
          itemInCart = {
            ...action.item,
            quantity: 1
          };
          newCart.push(itemInCart)
        };
        return {
          ...state,
          basket: newCart
        };
      default:
        return state;
```

Answer (score 0):

let newCart = [...state.basket]
let itemInCart = newCart.find((item) => item.id === action.item.id);

```
        if (itemInCart) {
            return {
                ...state,
                basket: [{...itemInCart, quantity: itemInCart.quantity++} ]
            }
        } else {
            return {
                ...state,
                basket: [...state.basket, action.item]
            }
        };
```

this work but if insert a new product replace the exist product in the cart

Answer (score -1):

I think `let newCart = [...state.basket]` is creating a new array, but copying the reference of the object in the cart, so you are mutating the state. Try

```
let itemInCart = newCart.find((item) => item.id === action.item.id);
let newItem;
  if (itemInCart) {
    newItem = {...itemInCart, quantity: itemInCart.quantity++}
  }else {
    newItem = {
    ...action.item,
    quantity:1
  };
newCart.push(newItem)
```

i.e copy the item in the cart into a new object and change the quantity.

Comment: let newCart = [...state.basket]
 let itemInCart = newCart.find((item) => item.id === action.item.id);

            if (itemInCart) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    basket: [{...itemInCart, quantity: itemInCart.quantity++} ]
                }
            } else {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    basket: [...state.basket, action.item]
                }
            };  this work but if insert a new product replace the exist product in the cart